# Default all projects to x86

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can i default all projects created to x86 in visual studio 2015?
They're always created as 'Any CPU' and i have to go into configuration manager and create another x86 build.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This is an excessively unwise thing to do, it is based on a complete misunderstanding what a solution platform means.  Starting with you changing the completely wrong setting, you never use configuration manager to target x86.  The only setting that matters is the jitter forcing on the EXE project, set in the project's Build tab.  The "Prefer 32-bit" option is already turned on by default.

Comment: What if i don't want a 'prefer' 32-bit option? What if i only want a 32-bit option? I know what you say, but seeing 'AnyCPU' on top makes me confuse sometimes on different projects and i always have to check what it is compiled for.